# Is bad practice to have spring boot starter project for starter project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

Spring boot starter project provides extensive set of functionalities auto configured. But for our application we want to have only a subset of functionality. May be only one feature out of the spring boot starter project. So is it advised to have custom starter project on top of spring boot provided starter project to mask some of the features or write new starter project directly from lower level libraries?

Comment: Spring boot provides **many** starters, each dedicated to one piece of tech that the framework supports: web, web reactive, jpa, test, etc. What areyou talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> Spring boot starter project provides extensive set of functionalities
>   auto configured

There are two  separate concerns you are talking about.

I think the auto configured part is something which is Spring boot's opinionated way of configuring. As an example if in classpath it finds a in-memory database library ( like [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)) it automatically creates a datasource (pointing to embedded in-memory database) which is available for autowiring without you writing the configuration in a Java config class. Of course you can create you own datasource of choice by including appropriate driver jar for that database. Similarly lots of other configurations are done by default by classpath scanning and availability of certain jars and classes.

The second part - is more of a dependency issue in general. Say you want to use web mvc part in Spring boot. This will require a consistent set of dependencies and transitive dependencies as well. Rather than finding  and declaring the dependency in your build tool of choice ( maven, gradle etc) it has created the concept of starter projects where you simply mention the parent and all the right dependencies would be pulled on. This gives a great way to correctly lock your dependencies. However if you want to include any different version than what is provided by boot starter ( provided there is no compatibility issues with those different versions) you can still add explicitly in your build tool. For e.g., maven will by default include the highest version of a particular dependency among all available via transitive dependencies when it resolves dependency for an artifact.